# Codeblocks compiles "wrong" cpp.sh does it correctly

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


double log2x;
double logx;


int main()

{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed;
    int lines;
    cout << "How many lines would you like to calculate? " << endl;
    cin >> lines;
    cout << "x             " << "  log10x        " << "  log2x          " <<   "logx " << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    int stepcount = 1;
    int exponentstep = 0;
    int logvariable;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < lines; i++)
    {

        logvariable = stepcount * pow(10,exponentstep);
        log10x = log10(logvariable);
        log2x = log2(logvariable);
        logx = log(logvariable);

        stepcount++;
        while (stepcount == 10)
        {
            stepcount = 1;
            exponentstep++;
        }
        cout << left << setw(10) << logvariable << left << "     " << setw(10) << log10x << "     " << setw(10) << log2x << "     " << setw(10) << logx << endl;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

it outputs the natural log functions for values 1-9 * 10^n, so 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 200 etc. I was pretty convinced what i had would work, but my codeblocks would give 10 correct answers and then 10 that were off by one. I tried cpp.sh and it worked beautifully. Not sure why at all? I couldn't get it to compile in visual studios at all and i didn't get a useful enough error message to figure it out. Any reason why codeblocks would mess up code that appears to be working otherwise? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
double log2x;
double logx;
//You forgot to declare log10x
double log10x;
```

You should copy the code into a text document and create a new project. Once you created a new project go to "view" then manager or shift+f2 and you should see your project. Make sure that the main.cpp is in the "Sources"under your project and paste the code, save it and compile it.

Everything worked for me and it looked like the correct answers once I declared the log10x so try to make a new project and if that doesn't help I believe your creating codeBlock projects incorrectly and I can walk you through it, its very simple.